# Problem installing UE5 via Linux Ubuntu terminal

Tags: installation, setup-deployment, gnome-terminal, unreal-engine5

First off, I'm a noob. So this is all new to me.

I downloaded Linux_Unreal_Engine_5.0.3.zip from unrealengine.com/en-US/linux and I also downloaded V20 clang-13.0.1-based as well as V19 clang-11.0.1-based just in case because I didn't know which would be compatible.

When I follow the directions on the docs.unrealengine.com site I get "No such file or directory". I extracted everything already and I only typed "./setup.sh" as instructed by the site.

I'd really appreciate someone's patient guidance with this. I've looked everywhere on the internet for a solution.

Comment: You should show the steps that lead up to "No such file or directory". It's such a generic error message that it doesn't help by itself.

Comment: I would have but it said that I'm not allowed to post pictures yet. I guess it's like Reddit with Karma points. I'm extra green like I said. I don;t know the terminal that well yet. And I don't know how to configure files so they can be located. Should I put everything in a folder and reference that? I only typed "./Setup.sh". That was the "Step 1" after installing and extracting the zip file.

Comment: You could tell what you've done so far without using images :)

Comment: (also: `./setup.sh` is _not_ the same as `./Setup.sh`)

Comment: I have come to understand that all too well lol I got the terminal to find "Setup.sh" by putting the file in the "Home" section of my files. But now the terminal  says "Installing a bundled clang toolchain"  but what follows this message is "./Setup.sh: line 46: pushd: Build/BatchFiles/Linux: No such file or directory" without any installation actions after it. I dragged all of the files to the "Home" section and the terminal still can't findthe files necessary for install. I've tried install UE4 from the source code via Github, but after install the editor didn't open when I clicked on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason UE5 Linux package is missing two sh files

```
SetupToolchain.sh
BuildThirdParty.sh
```

Signup for github unreal engine repository.
Then these files can be downloaded from here:
https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/SetupToolchain.sh
https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/BuildThirdParty.sh

- Just click raw and save it as sh instead txt (ctrl+s).
- Then right click these files>properties>permission>allow execute
- Then copy it in Unreal/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/
- sudo ./Setup.sh in terminal

Comment: 404 page not found

Comment: Should Accessing Unreal Engine source code on GitHub first: https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue-on-github

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was as simple as me typing "sudo" before "./Setup.sh".

Comment: When I run "sudo ./Setup.sh" It say: ./Setup.sh: line 47: ./SetupToolchain.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: @BorkoDjurovic refer to the answer, as that is the solution. you need to download those two files from github